# Is {% import ... %} a valid template tag?

Tags: django, django-templates

In a template, I see something like

```
{% import "macros.html" as macros %}
```

Is this a valid tag? I can't seem to find any documentation on it.

Thanks

Comment: I can't seem to find any documentation on it though. Any pointers?

Comment: It raises `TemplateSyntaxError` on django `1.4.X` please add your version info to the OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out: it's actually a jinja tag.

Comment: What made you think it's a Django tag at the first place?